# What's the difference between MySQL and local_host3306 when I use navicat for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, navicat

[image]

Their database look like same one,so why there have two rather than one?

Comment: Do you recall adding one/both of them?

Comment: When I edit something in MySQL and saved the change,then I open the same table in Local_host3306,I just find it has changed too.

Comment: I have never used Navicat but it seems these are just duplicates.  Backup your data and then try deleting the one you  don't want.

Comment: @秦文茂: This because you have saved two MySQL Connections with the different name and actually the connection details of the servers is same. so when you changed either of the server database you get the changes in other too.

Comment: Incidentally, choosing non-Roman characters for your username makes it almost impossible to respond directly to you on SO (I don't know why they allow it)

Comment: why a same accout can login at two different place?(I can login root accout in CMD and navicat at the same time ,but I can't understand .)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have two connections by mistake.

You can safely delete one of the connections (Not the database).

Just do a Right Click on the undesired connection and press "Delete Connection".